# Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function satisfying $f'(x)=f(x)+1$

Tags: calculus

I need help with this exercise.

Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function satisfying $f'(x)=f(x)+1$

a) Let $g(x)=f(x)e^{-x}$. Find $g'(x)$.

So this is what I did

$$g'(x)=f'(x)\cdot e^{-x}+e^{-x}\cdot -1 \cdot f(x)$$

$$g'(x)=f'(x)\cdot e^{-x}-e^{-x} \cdot f(x)$$

$$g'(x)=e^{-x}[f'(x)-f(x)]$$

$$g'(x)=e^{-x}[f(x)+1-f(x)]$$

$$g'(x)=e^{-x}[1]$$

$$g'(x)=e^{-x}$$

b) Find all the differentiable functions $f$ satisfying $f'(x)=f(x)+1$

I'm stuck with this one. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part just needs you to solve the differential equation. If you let $f(x) =y$, you can write $\frac {dy} {dx} = y+1$.

You can separate and integrate to get: $\int \frac 1{y+1}dy = \int 1 dx$.

You then get: $\ln|y+1| = x + c$, where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

Taking the exponent of both sides:

$|y+1| = e^xe^c = Ae^x$ (we're just assigning another constant $A>0$ such that $A = e^c$).

Now, since the right hand side is always positive, we can remove the absolute value sign and rearrange to get $y = \pm(Ae^x) - 1$, which you can write as: $f(x) =Be^x - 1, \ B \ne 0$.

You now note that when $B =0$, you get $f(x) = - 1$ which trivially satisfies the differential equation.

Hence the final solution is $f(x) = Be^x - 1$, without restriction on $B$. If you're working in the reals, $B$ can be any real number.

Comment: We're supposed to use the result of (a) to solve (b).

Comment: @mr_e_man You can, but unless they specially said "hence..." in the question, it's really up to one what method they use. Your answer is nice and short, so it's likely that's what they "intended". I'll upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$g'(x)=e^{-x}$$

$$g(x)=-e^{-x}+C$$

$$f(x)=g(x)e^x=-1+Ce^x$$

Answer (score 0):

You should really have explained in your question that you needed to use (a) to solve (b).

Spoilers ahead: click each one for a hint. (In the following, DE stands for Differential Equation)

> Can you rewrite the DE for f using what you got in (a)?

> $f(x)= g(x)e^x$, so what is f' using the product rule?

> Anyway, have you learned about "integrating factor", or "exact differentials"?

Comment: The OP isn't the author of the exercise, and probably didn't know that (a) and (b) were supposed to be connected. (I'm not the author either, but I think it's clear what was intended.)